# Add Dataframe to list of dataframes

Tags: python, list, dataframe, addition

I have the following list of Dataframes twice:
[image: List of Dataframes]

Now i want to combine these lists to one list. So i want to add all the Dataframes from list two to list one.

Simple example:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([2,3,4,5])
b = pd.DataFrame([4,7,8,9,10])

c = [a,b]

d = pd.DataFrame([2,3,4,5])
e = pd.DataFrame([4,7,8,9,10])

f = [d,e]

# New list automatically:
g = [a,b,d,e]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to expand your list:

```
g = c + f
```

For example:

```
[1, 2, 3] + [4, 5, 6]
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Perfect, that was easy! Thanks!